# How to convert a vector to a map according to this rule?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

### SOLVED BY SELF

```clj
(defn parse-args
  ([args]
   (parse-args args {}))
  ([[fst sec & more] rst]
   (let [value? (fn [x] (and (not (keyword? x))
                             (not (map? x))))]
     (cond
       (and (keyword? fst)
            (keyword? sec)) (parse-args (cons sec more) (merge rst {fst true}))
       (and (keyword? fst)
            (value? sec)) (parse-args more (merge rst {fst sec}))
       :else rst
       ))))
```

---

*im new to clojure

for example there is a vec like below:

```clj
[:enchant :type "Fire Aspect" :level 123]
```

try to convert it to:

```clj
{:enchant true :type "Fire Aspect" :level 123}
```

note that the original vec has been somehow 'interleaved'
but not every key has its 'value' (like `:enchant`)
and i just want to find out those and treat them as a boolean value
with `true` as their default value

---

i've tried to use:

```clj
(defn parse-arg [args toggle-coll]
  (let [is-value? #(not (and (keyword? %)
                             (map? %1)))]
    (reduce (fn [k1 k2]
              (merge
                (cond
                  (and (keyword? k1)
                       (keyword? k2)) ({} {k1 true})
                  (and (keyword? k1)
                       (is-value? k2)) ({} {}) ; and soon i found this method is difficult and clumsy
                  (and (map? k1)
                       (is-value? k2)) ({} {})
                  (and (map? k1)
                       (keyword? k2)) ({} {})
                  ;; omitted)
                )
              )
            args)))
```

Comment: @amalloy, that is not a duplicate of seq -> hash-map conversion, it is about deducing absent values in the input vector defaulting them to `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can also process the input data by the windows of 2 items and insert `true` between two keywords:

```
(defn parse-args [data]
  (->> (concat data [::end])
       (partition 2 1)
       (mapcat (fn [[a :as pair]] 
                 (if (every? keyword? pair)
                   [a true]
                   [a])))
       (apply hash-map)))
```

the `::end` kv is added to handle the dangling keyword in the end of the sequence, if any.

```
user> (parse-args [:a :b 1 :c 10 :d])
;;=> {:c 10, :b 1, :d true, :a true}
```

Comment: Nice solution! I added something similar but decided to remove it again because I forgot about handling that dangling `::end`.

Answer (score 2):

[clojure.spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) can be used to express a regular language for handling the missing values. Here, we define a spec `::input` for the mini-language:

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s])

(spec/def ::input (s/* (s/cat :k keyword? :v (s/? (complement keyword?)))))
```

Then we can parse the input vector using [`conform`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.spec.alpha/conform) and put it [`into`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into) a map using a [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map)ping transducer:

```
(defn parse-args [args]
  (into {}
        (map (juxt :k #(:v % true)))
        (s/conform ::input args)))
```